# Jquery firing twice in the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble with the jquery, at the moment using v2.1, the problem is that it is firing the below twice! 
I cant get this work, don't know why this is happening :(

```
$(document).on('click', '#task-list li.listing', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("hello!"); 
    $(".hiddentaskedit").show();
    $(".lefthelp1").hide();
    $("#task-list>li.list-group-item").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#listsbtfrm")[0].reset();
    $("#datatextchk").focus();
    var a = $(this).children(".view").children(".checkbox").children(".task-name1").html();
    var b = $(this).children(".view").children(".checkbox").children(".task-name2").html(); 
    var c = $(this).children(".view").children(".checkbox").children(".task-name3").html();     
    if(a.length>0){ $("#datatextchk").val(a); }
    if(b.length>0){ $("#datatextchk2").val(b); }
    if(c.length>0){ $("#datatextchk3").val(c); }
    return false;
    });
```

wv

Comment: Are you having any other click events rather than this.?

Comment: To see the exact problem you are having, please try and isolate the behavior on a minimal page and post it on http://jsfiddle.net/.
Before I make suggestions, I need to test them for myself in your environment.

Comment: Indeed, purely this script you've posted is triggering just once, as you can see [on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mKzmG/), so must be something else on your page that's causing the issue. Thus, more information required.

Comment: The problem is if I dont reload the page the call is twice else once, and I dont want the page to reload.

Comment: I don't think this question should be flagged as **Off-topic** because it is according to what SO says. yes you can probably call it **Duplicate** because SO has many questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it is working good

```
 $(document).unbind('click').on('click', '#task-list li.listing', function(e)
 {
       alert('Hellow world');
       e.stopPropagation();
       return false;
 });
```

And it's definitely Javascript problem because if you hit google and search for **event fire twice** you will see that Angular, Jquery and backbone etc all are somewhere firing events twice or even thrice. So, it's seem that it's javascript behind this.

Comment: The second one is working in which we called the variable to check "true/false" but I have lots of "click" functions do I have to use this in every 1 of them? Is there any other universal method :) Also I will be clicking few classes and this will not work on them !

Comment: @JamesMitchee see what Rishabh has suggested for your query regarding second example of mine give common class to each

Comment: @JamesMitchee See my 3rd example it's working good. Hope that works good with you as well

Comment: You are welcome Dear. By the way which one worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

That's because of having `e.stopPropagation();` after `e.preventDefault();`. Try using `e.preventDefault();` after `e.stopPropagation();`.

Since `e.stopPropagation();` stops the flow to relative elements where as `e.preventDefault();` stops natural flow, in other words,

**`e.stopPropagation();`** stops the event from bubbling up the event chain.

**`e.preventDefault();`** prevents the default action the browser makes on that event.

```
$(document).on('click', '#task-list li.listing', function(e){
    alert("hello!"); 
    $(".hiddentaskedit").show();
    $(".lefthelp1").hide();
    $("#task-list>li.list-group-item").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#listsbtfrm")[0].reset();
    $("#datatextchk").focus();
    var a = $(this).children(".view").children(".checkbox").children(".task-name1").html();
    var b = $(this).children(".view").children(".checkbox").children(".task-name2").html(); 
    var c = $(this).children(".view").children(".checkbox").children(".task-name3").html();     
    if(a.length>0){ $("#datatextchk").val(a); }
    if(b.length>0){ $("#datatextchk2").val(b); }
    if(c.length>0){ $("#datatextchk3").val(c); }
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    });
```

If it still does not work remove `e.preventDefault();` from the code i.e. =>

```
    $(document).on('click', '#task-list li.listing', function(e){
    alert("hello!"); 
    $(".hiddentaskedit").show();
    $(".lefthelp1").hide();
    $("#task-list>li.list-group-item").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#listsbtfrm")[0].reset();
    $("#datatextchk").focus();
    var a = $(this).children(".view").children(".checkbox").children(".task-name1").html();
    var b = $(this).children(".view").children(".checkbox").children(".task-name2").html(); 
    var c = $(this).children(".view").children(".checkbox").children(".task-name3").html();     
    if(a.length>0){ $("#datatextchk").val(a); }
    if(b.length>0){ $("#datatextchk2").val(b); }
    if(c.length>0){ $("#datatextchk3").val(c); }
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
    });
```

I have written the both functions at bottom of function as it supports other browsers(in my experiment of using it above, my function was breaking).

**Update**

**1.** As you want for dynamic (and you did not mention that before), you'll have to use **live** event instead of **on**

change this **$(document).on('click', '#task-list li.listing', function(e){**

*to* **$( selector ).live( events, data, handler ){**                // jQuery 1.3+

or
As suggested by *AbdulJabbarWebBestow* **live** is depreciated, either way you can use **delegate**

**$( document ).delegate( '#task-list li.listing', "click", function(e) {** // jQuery 1.4.3+

**2.** **More details** (*source* http://api.jquery.com/live/ )

```
jQuery attempts to retrieve the elements specified by the selector before calling the .live() method, which may be time-consuming on large documents.


Chaining methods is not supported. For example, $( "a" ).find( ".offsite, .external" ).live( ... );  is not valid and does not work as expected.


Since all .live() events are attached at the document element, events take the longest and slowest possible path before they are handled.


On mobile iOS (iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch) the click event does not bubble to the document body for most elements and cannot be used with .live() without applying one of the following workarounds:


Use natively clickable elements such as a or button, as both of these do bubble to document.
Use .on() or .delegate() attached to an element below the level of document.body, since mobile iOS does bubble within the body.


Apply the CSS style cursor:pointer to the element that needs to bubble clicks (or a parent including document.documentElement). Note however, this will disable copy\paste on the element and cause it to be highlighted when touched.


Calling event.stopPropagation() in the event handler is ineffective in stopping event handlers attached lower in the document; the event has already propagated to document.


The .live() method interacts with other event methods in ways that can be surprising, e.g., $( document ).off( "click" ) removes all click handlers attached by any call to .live()!
```

For pages still using .live(), this list of version-specific differences may be helpful:

Before jQuery 1.7, to stop further handlers from executing after one bound using .live(), the handler must return false.
Calling .stopPropagation() will not accomplish this.
As of jQuery 1.4 the .live() method supports custom events as well as all JavaScript events that bubble. 
It also supports certain events that don't bubble, including change, submit, focus and blur.

In jQuery 1.3.x only the following JavaScript events could be bound: click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup.

**3.** As you commented on *AbdulJabbarWebBestow* ,

> The second one is working in which we called the variable to check
>   "true/false" but I have lots of "click" functions do I have to use
>   this in every 1 of them? Is there any other universal method :) Also I
>   will be clicking few classes and this will not work on them ! –

Ans= Better give common class name to all of your required html elements, that you want to handle and use id for unique identification. Try using **this** inside function of the event, example **this.id** would return the id of that class name. This method is standard way for handling dynamic elements and so called universal :) .

I hope this helped you.

Please let me know for further doubts/clarification.

Comment: Not working dont know whats the problem :(

Comment: @JamesMitchee did you try 2nd example, please post html code also if that did not work.

Comment: I tried the same code 2nd one, it not working dynamically. With that I mean you build a dynamic li class and then fire this function it will not work :(

Comment: @JamesMitchee YOU shouhld have mentioned before that you want dynamically, see my updated answer

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). for more check http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow yeah you are right, but that can be still used, i'll update my answer.

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow  no mention :)

Comment: thanks it clarifies everything, I think I will downgrade to earlier 1.4 version. :)

Comment: @JamesMitchee iam glad it helped you, i would suggest also you to not downgrade you version as i mentioned it 1.4+ (not 1.4), it means that all versions of jquery including 1.4 and above, you can still ask me for doubts :)